# How can I run another gulpfile in current gulpfile

Tags: gulp

I need to run another gulp file before the 'default' task in current gulp file. Is there any gulp plugin for this situation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`child_process.exec(...)`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) to run the both gulp tasks like you would from the console using the CLI API. There is `Gulp.run` but that function is deprecated and will be removed moving forward.

This snippet will run both gulp files below in succession.

#### run-two-gulp-files.js

To run: `node run-two-gulp-files.js`

`./gulpfile.js` depends on `./other-thing-with-gulpfile/gulpfile.js`

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

// Run the dependency gulp file first
exec('gulp --gulpfile ./other-thing-with-gulpfile/gulpfile.js', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('other-thing-with-gulpfile/gulpfile.js:');
    console.log(stdout);
    if(error) {
        console.log(error, stderr);
    }
    else {

        // Run the main gulp file after the other one finished
        exec('gulp --gulpfile ./gulpfile.js', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
            console.log('gulpfile.js:');
            console.log(stdout);
            if(error) {
                console.log(error, stderr);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

#### gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var replace = require('gulp-replace');

gulp.task('file1-txt', function() {
    return gulp.src('file1.txt')
        .pipe(replace(/foo/g, 'bar'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['file1-txt']);
```

#### other-thing-with-gulpfile/gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var replace = require('gulp-replace');

gulp.task('file2-txt', function() {
    return gulp.src('file2.txt')
        .pipe(replace(/baz/g, 'qux'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('../dest'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['file2-txt']);
```